# C NULL is the same as empty struct

Tags: c, struct, null

So say I have a basic struct with just a couple of values:

```
struct my_struct {
    int val1;
    int val2;
}
```

and I want to pass it to a function

```
int test_the_struct(struct my_struct *s);
```

and then inside that function I check for NULL and returns an error code, but I want it to continue if an empty struct is passed instead. For example:

```
struct my_struct *test_struct = (struct test_struct *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct test_struct));
test_the_struct(NULL); //this should fail
test_the_struct(test_struct); //this should not fail
```

How could I differentiate between the two? In this situation, I CANNOT alter the structure of `my_struct`

Comment: check to see if the pointer is NULL...

Comment: like you can check `if(s==NULL)....`

Comment: And don't cast the return value of `calloc` or `malloc`... it could well be hiding errors in your code here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just don't have a problem.

Just check the pointer against `NULL` and you are fine.

```
int test_the_struct(struct my_struct *s)
{
    if (s) { // or if (s != NULL) or whatever you want to express it...
        return s->val1 + s->val2;
    } else {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

If you call it with your `test_struct`, both values are `0`. There is nothing wrong or special about it.

Comment: apparently I don't. My code was failing elsewhere and I just had tunnel vision. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find if a pointer `s` is null you can use

```
if (s) {
    /* not null */
} else {
    /* is null */
}
```

A pointer to an "empty" struct is not null.

Answer (score 0):

design your function as belows

```
int test_the_struct(void *ptr)
{
if (ptr == NULL)
     return -1; //error
else 
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: should use struct my_struct *ptr but if you pass it any other pointer then compiler will give warning..so to avoid that just use void * pointer...

Comment: @Mr.32: But you don't know what OP does inside the function. What if he tries to dereference it? dereferencing a void pointer is a bit of a no-no